# Define a value depending on categorical variables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Hello all and happy new year!

I am trying to build a tool to evaluate skills. I defined different skills and each is skill is caracterized by its level.

Example :

- Skills 1 is Level 1
- Skills 2 is Level 2

Then the user will complete a cell to say "OK" or "NOK".

To assess the skills for one user I would like something like :
ALL LEVEL 1 MUST BE ON "OK" TO DEFINE THE ASSESMENT CELL TO "DONE"

and this for each level.

Could you help me on this matter ? I don't know where to start

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Some combination of `IF` and `AND`? What have you tried? Note that if you use `1` and `0` rather than `OK` and `NOK` you could use `SUM`. `COUNTIF` is also a natural fit, as @cyboashu suggests.

Comment: Read this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2 and this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I tried this :
IF(AND(COUNTIF(B2:B7;"Level 1");SUM(D2:D3)=2);"DONE";"TO DO"))
and it's not working. Where did I do a mistake ? 
What if my level is not in a good order ? (example Level 2 and Level 0). Would I be able to use the same formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and you're trying to calculate the number of Level 0, Level 1, Level 2, and Level 3 skills each user has in total, only looking at those skills that have a "Done" in column D, you could use this:

=COUNTIFS(D2:D7,"Done",B2:B7,"Level 0")

From here, you can update as needed for the other levels.